# Cannot convert lambda expression

Tags: development, list-item

I am trying to retrive an email of user in  list.

I have this compilation error context.Load:

> Error 1   Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>[]'
>   because it is not a delegate type

Here is my code:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listitems = list.GetItems(query);

            context.Load(listitems, item => item["MyUser"]); // compilation error here
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            User u = null;
            foreach (ListItem item in listitems)
            {

                FieldUserValue fuv = (FieldUserValue)item["MyUser"];
                 u = context.Web.EnsureUser(fuv.LookupValue);
                res = u.Email;

            }
```

Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: #Amal Hashim , like you suggested  I get the name 'i' does not exist in the current Context.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `context.Load(listitems, i=>i.Include(i=>i["MyUser"]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `context.Load(listitems, items => items.Include(item => item["MyUser"]));`